# AWK: find out if running on windows

Tags: windows, awk

How can i find out whether i am on Windows or not?

I need to execute an OS specific command in AWK.

Specifically, i want to
`system("mkdir DIR")` on windows and
`system("mkdir -p DIR")` everywhere else (Unix/Linux/OS X/BSD),
to create a directory recursively.

Comment: I guess you can do `{if (!system("uname > /dev/null")) print "*nix"}`. (I suppose there is no `uname` on Windows).

Comment: yeah, no uname on windows, and no /dev/null either, so this would most likely create an error message on windows, which is not desirable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I can't test this answer because I don't have access to a `Windows` system, but give a try to the `ENVIRON` variable. Linux and Unix paths are separated with `:` while `Windows` paths are separated with `;`. You could check it, something like:

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        is_windows = 0;
        if ( index( ENVIRON["PATH"], ";" ) > 0 ) {
            is_windows = 1;
        }
    }
    ...
' input-file
```

This could fail if there is only one directory in the `Windows` path, but I hope you get the idea. Perhaps a combination of several environment variables or something similar could be more helpful.

Comment: see my own answer below, for a slightly improved version of this one

Answer (score 3):

This is a slightly optimized version of the one by [Birei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/773159/birei).

The `OS` environment var is only and (supposedly) always specified on windows, and it should always contain some form of the string "windows", for example "Windows_NT".

```
awk '
    BEGIN {
        is_windows = 0;
        if (index(tolower(ENVIRON["OS"]), "windows") > 0) {
            is_windows = 1;
        }
    }
    ...
' input-file
```

Thanks to the guys from #awk and [Birei](https://stackoverflow.com/users/773159/birei)!

Comment: If Birei's answer led to your solution, don't forget to give him credit by clicking the checkmark beside his answer.

Comment: the checkmark... but i though it is meant to mark the correct/best answer, and my answer is better, even though most of it is copied from his. so... i want others to read my answer, when they have the same problem, not his. should i not rather set the checkmark on my answer?

Comment: If most of it was copied from his, then he deserves the credit.  It's great that you were able to use it.  If you don't give credit, he doesn't get the points, and has little incentive to answer future questions from you.  Note that if you give your own answer the check mark, you don't get the points for it.

Comment: i dont care about the points, and i want him to getthe credits, but more important to me, is that people with the same problem, will use the best response as reference. can i not somehow split the credit and the correct answer to two different answers?

Comment: You may not care, but others do.  You can't "split the credit", but you can add an update to your question showing how you used the answer from Birei, or you could add comments to his answer.